# Webpack / NPM: Use build version of installed module instead of re-building from source

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, dat.gui

I would like to use the dat.GUI library for a project that's build with Webpack 2. If I install the module via `npm -install --save-dev dat.gui` and then try to import it using `import * as DAT from 'dat.gui';` I get the following error when Webpack is trying to compile my project:

```
ERROR in ./~/dat.gui/src/dat/controllers/NumberControllerSlider.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'style' in 
'/home/me/myProject/node_modules/dat.gui/src/dat/controllers'
BREAKING CHANGE: It's no longer allowed to omit the '-loader' suffix 
when using loaders.
```

I know this error occurs when using Webpack 2 to build Webpack 1 based projects. But why is Webpack even trying to build the module if there already is a build version inside `node_modules/dat.gui/build';`? Is there a way to tell Webpack or NPM to use the existing build version without trying to re-build it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When importing a node module, webpack looks into its `package.json` and uses the [`main` field](https://github.com/dataarts/dat.gui/blob/191eb65b3af51519a6f36e00af2fcc596445b3f8/package.json#L5) as entry of the module, similar to what Node.js does (webpack looks for more fields by default, see [`resolve.mainFields`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-mainfields)).

Since for `dat.gui` the main field does not point to the built version but to the source, which actually inlines loaders as seen in [dat.gui@0.6.1 - NumberControllerSlider.js](https://unpkg.com/dat.gui@0.6.1/src/dat/controllers/NumberControllerSlider.js) for the `styleSheet` import, and that is not a good idea in general and certainly not to publish.

But you can import the built version by specifying the corresponding path. So your import would be:

```
import * as DAT from 'dat.gui/build/dat.gui.js';
```

If you'd like to still import just `dat.gui` you can configure [`resolve.alias`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-alias) to point to the built version as follows:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    'dat.gui': 'dat.gui/build/dat.gui.js'
  }
}
```

With that you can use your original import statement:

```
import * as DAT from 'dat.gui';
```